# How to fetch extra info from related field after faceting items from Solr?

Tags: solr

Solr items:

```js
[
  { slug: "foo", title: "The foo", stuff: 1 },
  { slug: "foo", title: "The foo", stuff: 2 },
  { slug: "bar", title: "The bar", stuff: 3 },
]
```

On these items I need to do two operations:

1. aggregate/facet items by slug to generate report like this one:

```js
[
    {
        slug: "foo",
        title: "The foo",
        count: 2,
    },
    {
        slug: "bar",
        title: "The bar",
        count: 1,
    }
]
```

2. filter items by slug, for example when `slug == "foo"`:

```js
[
  { slug: "foo", title: "The foo", stuff: 1 },
  { slug: "foo", title: "The foo", stuff: 2 },
]
```

## The problem

With current schema (separated slug and title fields) we can easily filter items (`?q=slug:foo`),  but faceting by slug while including title into result is impossible (`?facet.field=slug` will return only list of slugs and items counts for each facet-group).

---

#### Potential solution #1

Alternative schema looks like this:

```js
[
  { slug_title: "foo:The foo", stuff: 1 },
  { slug_title: "foo:The foo", stuff: 2 },
  { slug_title: "bar:The bar", stuff: 3 },
]
```

With this schema we can facet like this: `?facet.query=slug_title` and generate report by splitting values from the result: `slug, title = facet_value.split(":")`

And filter like this: `?q=slug_title:foo:*`

While this alternative schema works - it looks kinda ugly and probably slower because uses "fuzzy" filtering.

---

#### Potential solution #2

Simplify schema to this:

```js
[
  { slug: "foo", stuff: 1 },
  { slug: "foo", stuff: 2 },
  { slug: "bar", stuff: 3 },
]
```

... and store slug-title mapping somewhere else (eg main database):

```js
{
    foo: "The foo",
    bar: "The bar",
}
```

This solution looks cleaner but it is much more slower, because for every request to the Solr we also need to fetch mapper from main database.

---

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about [Pivot faceting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/faceting.html#Faceting-Pivot_DecisionTree_Faceting) or [using the JSON Facet API with multiple facets under each other](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/json-facet-api.html)? (i.e. one for slugs, and then a facet under that one again for title)? This will give you `foo: {"The Foo": 4, "The bar": 8}`

Comment: My company uses Solr 5.5, so I guess "facet bucketing" from json api is not supported. But pivots look like just what I need. Do know about how severe is performance penalty for this cascade faceting?

Comment: Performance depends on _many_ factors, so in most cases; just try it. It'll probably be more than performant enough.